# Replace a string containing arbitrary special characters

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to replace a string inside a text file using `sed`. This string could contain any special character like `.`, `/`, `$`, etc. However, I'm interested to replace such a string *literally*, that is to not interpret `.`, `/`, `$`, etc. as special characters.

So, the simple instruction

`sed -i s|$old|$new| "$path_to_file"`

doesn't work as I expect if I want to replace `20.8` with `20.9` for example.

Of course, before starting the script that uses this `sed`, I don't have any idea where the special characters will be placed by the user.

Is there a way to do this with `sed` or any other tools (`perl`, `awk`, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: write a func to quote the special chars so for `20.8` it'll become `20\.8` after being quoted.

Comment: note that some chars in `$new` also need to be quoted. e.g. `/`, `&`, ...

Comment: Also see [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/4154375).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/422459/substitution-in-text-file-without-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file does not contain nulls and will fit comfortably in memory, you can just use bash parameter expansion directly:

```bash
data=$(<"$path_to_file")
echo "${data//"$old"/"$new"}" >"$path_to_file"
```

Don't forget the double-quotes, they disable special pattern characters.

---

Notes:

1. `date=$(...)` strips trailing newlines; use `mapfile` to keep them
2. `echo` can produce unintended output in some corner conditions; use `printf` to avoid them

So, slightly longer but much improved version:

```
mapfile -d '' data <"$path_to_file"
printf '%s' "${data//"$old"/"$new"}" >"$path_to_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for refining your (already) excellent answer. Could you tell me why are you using the `-d ''` option?

Comment: consider: `old=$'\nb'; new='-'; printf 'a\nbc\nd' >f; mapfile a <f; declare -p a; echo "[${a//"$old"/"$new"}]"; mapfile -d '' a <f; declare -p a; echo "[${a//"$old"/"$new"}]"`

Comment: Basically, you want everything stuffed into the first array element otherwise matching can fail if `$old`  includes the delmiter. And ignoring that you'd have to use `"${data[*]//...}"` or somesuch.