# Sed not replacing variabes with backslashes

Tags: sed, replace

So, I am trying to change directories using sed, but I can't seem to get the find and replace to work.

I am inputting

```
d="D:\X-docs\X\"
echo $d
p=$(pwd)
f=${p}"/"
```

and I am getting the correct output of

```
D:\X-docs\X\
```

but when I use

```
sed -i "s|${d}|${f}|g" $file
```

$d is not getting replaced with $f, but no error is being displayed indicating there was an incomplete sed command.

The line it should be replacing in the file is

```
%chk=D:\X-docs\X\abc_1.gjf
```

I have also tried setting $d to:

```
d="D:\X-docs\X\\"
d=D:\\X-docs\\X\\
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a string containing arbitrary special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482915/replace-a-string-containing-arbitrary-special-characters)

Comment: @jhnc I have over 1,000 files and multiple replacements in each. Do you know if that will do it iteratively? Also, what do they mean by "file does not contain nulls"? I am currently running this in a forloop.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @jhnc If what I am understanding is correct, then the files might contain nulls.

Comment: btw. your "I am inputting" code is not your actual code

Comment: `d='D:\\X-docs\\X\\'`

Comment: Add `d=${d//\\/\\\\}` just before `sed` call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern